# Java Mission Control No JVMs detected Windows 10

Tags: java, jmc

I just downloaded [Java Mission Control](http://jdk.java.net/jmc/) (JMC) for the first time and upon starting JMC, the following popup appears:

[image: JMC error popup]

I am trying to go through the [Q&A](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2579717/jmc-frequently-asked-questions) but I am either not sure how to implement the suggested solutions, or the solutions don't seem to work, which I detail below:

[image: Q&A]

### My attempted solutions

Referring to the suggested solutions enumerated above:

1. A1: I am not running in Eclipse (I am running the JMC app directly as an executable), and anyway **what does it mean to "run an app on a JDK, not a JRE"?**
2. A2: Indeed the hsperfdata folder was not writeable, so I modified the folder to give all permissions to everyone and closed all Java apps:

[image: hsperfdata]

However, *after starting a new Java app*, **the permissions revert back to their original settings** and thus I am unable to implement this suggested solution:

[image: reverted permissions]

- A3: The line after -vm is not empty, so I don't think this suggested solution is relevant for me:

[image: vm options]

For what it's worth, both JConsole and JVisualVM **are able to find all running Java processes:**
[image: jconsole]
[image: jvisualvm]

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful for others with the same issue, I was able to resolve the problem described above by adding the location of the JRE *contained within the JDK* to the front of the **System** PATH variable (Windows 10):

[image]

[image: path var]

Comment: In the end it looks like your issue was indeed caused by the "java" program version that your system was using. Changing the order in your PATH variable must have caused the windows operating system to use the version in your JDK rather than the one in the JRE.  Could you check if there isn't a Java "JDK" entry further down your PATH variable?